# How can I compute molar concentration if I am given parts per trillion?

Tags: physical-chemistry, concentration

A question in my book asks...

You have a gas X that is found in quantities of $261~\mathrm{PPTV}$ (parts per trillion by volume). Compute the molar concentration at $283.15~\mathrm{K}$ and $101325~\mathrm{Pa}$.

Would you just find the volume using $\frac{n\mathcal{R}T}{P}$ for $1~\mathrm{mol}$ of gas, then multiply this answer by $261/10^{12}$?

Comment: @hey It is better to use `$\mathrm{...}$` instead of `\text{...}$` and also the use of braces is highly recommended to avoid breaking away of the argument. See also here: http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945

Comment: @Martin I will take care of it next time.

Answer (score 3):

I have the feeling, that this is a superbly stupid question. And I also have the feeling that it is quite possible, that my answer will be wrong.
First of all the [parts-per-notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parts-per_notation) should be avoided as it is not compliant with SI and highly ambiguous.
Secondly, it generally may only refer to a unitless number - a molar concentration has a unit ($\mathrm{mol/L}$).

The here used unit may refer to a couple of things. In general its meaning should most likely refer to $\mathrm{PPTV = 10^{-12}L/L}$. Sometimes the use of $\mathrm{PPTV = 10^{-12}g/L}$

From here you can probably make your best guesses, determining how many moles of compound do you have:
\begin{align}
pV &=n\mathcal{R}T\\
n  &= \frac{pV}{\mathcal{R}T}\\
n  &= \frac{101325~\mathrm{Pa}\cdot 261\cdot10^{-12}~\mathrm{L}}{8.314~\mathrm{\frac{J}{mol\cdot K}}283.15~\mathrm{K}}\\
n  &= 1.12\cdot10^{-8}~\mathrm{mol} &\implies c&=  1.12\cdot10^{-8}~\mathrm{\frac{mol}{L}}
\end{align}

If you have the mass given, then you need to know which gas it is, as $n=\frac{m}{M}$.

Another possible use could be the particles by volume notation, so it could also refer to $\mathrm{PPTV = 10^{-12}/m^3}$. (Apparently this is somewhat common in ecological air measurements.) Here you simply have to use $n=\frac{N}{\mathcal{N}_\mathrm{A}}$ to figure out the concentration in $\mathrm{mol/L}$.

Comment: Thanks! I got the same answer but the question was so vague that I wasn't sure if it's correct.

Comment: In truth, the $ppX$ designation is defined on a mass basis, not on a volume basis. Some key assumptions must be applied about the affects of the additive on the solvent to convert the mass basis to a volume basis.

Comment: @JeffreyWeimer I really do not understand what you want to say with your comment. Where do you get your definition from? As far as I can see, there is no official definition for this scheme. And could you elaborate more on what you mean with 'mass basis' please.